# Странное поведение recycleview и данных в нем

Tags: java, android, sql, recyclerview

В общем в recycleview загружаются данные из бд. Проверил на одном телефоне – все норм. Проверил на втором, а там список отображается не в том порядке. В запросе SQL указал конкретно сортировку по id, однако ничего не изменилось. В чем может быть дело?

```
private void loadingLevel() {
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM levels ORDER BY level_id", null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        if (c.getCount() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                map.put(c.getInt(0), c.getString(1));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        c.close();
    }

// заполнение листа для адаптера
    private void fillList() {
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            int id = entry.getKey();
            String word = entry.getValue();

            if (id <= currentLevel)
                aList.add(new Word(id, word));
            else
                aList.add(new Word(id, "?"));
        }
    }


    // отображение введенных слов
    private void showEnteredWords() {
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        LevelAdapter adapter = new LevelAdapter(this, aList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); // устанавливаем адаптер

        adapter.setOnWordClickListener(position -> {
            Word word = adapter.getWords().get(position);

            if (word.getId() < currentLevel) {
                AllRhymesFragment dialog = new AllRhymesFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("level", word.getId());
                args.putString("requestFrom", getClass().getSimpleName());
                dialog.setArguments(args);
                dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialogAllRhymes");
            } else
                Toasty.error(this, getString(R.string.access_is_closed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, false).show();
        });
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего вы используете HashMap, а он не гарантирует сохранение порядка добавленных элементов при итерации по нему.

Если вы замените его на LinkedHashMap то порядок сохранится.

Также, в случае сортировки по id подойдёт и TreeMap(сортирует ключи по возрастанию), но только для этого конкретного случая.

Comment: Не, я использую ArrayList

Comment: @СергейГуков Похоже, что используете. В самом начале вы добавляете значения из БД в map.put(c.getInt(0), c.getString(1)); А после оттуда уже в arralist. Собственно вам нужно изменить тип map и проблема должна решиться.

Comment: @Olmicron да точно, спасибо, как-то зациклилось внимание только на aList, а он ArrayList